# Emacs - disable wordwrapping in html-mode

Tags: emacs

In my emacs html-mode word wrapping happens if cross the legendary limit of 80 columns. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Word-wrapping in Emacs is done using the minor mode `auto-fill-mode`. You can disable it by running the command `M-x auto-fill-mode RET`, or by adding it to a hook:

```lisp
(defun my-html-mode-hook ()
  (auto-fill-mode -1))

(add-hook 'html-mode-hook 'my-html-mode-hook)
```

Comment: Can be made more compact:  `(add-hook 'html-mode-hook (lambda () (auto-fill-mode -1)))`

Comment: @bronger, it might be smaller, but adding lambdas to hooks has some drawbacks. The major one is that when you are developing your hook, you can easily end up having multiple versions of it attached to a hook variable -- this would never happen if you add a function symbol.  In this light, I would strongly discourage you from doing it.

Comment: @Lindydancer, but having the lambda in .emacs should be safe.  And my long .emacs file is grateful for 1 line instead of 4.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your .emacs:

```lisp
(defun my-html-mode-setup ()
  (auto-fill-mode -1))
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook 'my-html-mode-setup)
```